# flask - If-else only outputs 'if' condition

Tags: python

I have this program for PM levels detection and to output a message describing the level condition:

```py
def pm25warnings():
    pm25 = getLastData()
    #if pm25 <= "50" :
    if pm25 <= 50 : #edited
        message = "PM 2.5 level is normal"
    else:
        message = "PM 2.5 level is high"
    return message

def pm10warnings():
    pm10 = getLastData()
    #if pm10 <="50":
    if pm10 <= 50: #edited
        message2 = "PM 10 level is normal"
    else:
        message2 = "PM 10 level is high"
    return message2
```

`@app.route`

```py
    @app.route("/")
def index():
    time, temp, co, pm25, pm10 = getLastData()
    message = pm25warnings()
    message2 = pm10warnings()
    templateData = {
        'time'  : time,
        'temp'  : temp,
        'co'    : co,
        'pm25'  : pm25,
        'pm10'  : pm10,
        'message' : message,
        'message2' : message2,
        'numSamples'    : numSamples,
    }
    return render_template('index2.html', **templateData)
```

Might be useful to see:

```py
    def getLastData():
    try:
        lock.acquire(True)
        for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM sensors ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"):
            time = str(row[0])
            temp = row[1]
            co = row[2]
            pm25 = row[3]
            pm10 = row[4]
        return time, temp, co, pm25, pm10
    conn.close()
    finally:
        lock.release()
```

I made a script to make random big numbers to trigger a high value level. But the wrong statement is shown in the html page:

[image: html page showing wrong statement]

... or perhaps is there other ways for me to implement this?

How can this be? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I have edited the program thanks to the answers below but the page still shows the wrong statement:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** `pm25` and `pm10` is of TEXT datatype in the database (SQLite3). This problem might be a bit silly, given that my datatype is `TEXT` and not `NUMERICAL`, then, I couldn't do an e.g `if pm25 < 100` because `pm25` is 'TEXT`

Comment: if pm25 and pm50 are integers, remove the " " in the if statement because right now you are comparing the value with the ascii code of character 5 and character 0 and not with the the number 50

Comment: I forgot that the datatype for `pm25` and `pm10` on the database is `TEXT` (SQLite3)

Comment: @RonaldoEscobar have you had any success with this issue / are there further updates needed?

Answer (score 2):

<s>The statement `if pm25 <= "50"` is comparing `pm25` to the literal string `"50"`, not the number `50`. If `pm25` is a number, you need to remove the quotes.</s>

```py
    if pm25 <= 50 :
        message = "PM 2.5 level is normal"
    else:
        message = "PM 2.5 level is high"
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/RegularOrdinaryTypes)

After reading the comments posted on this answer, the data is being passed in as type `string`, with an example being `"9.8\n"`. I forget if python lets you compare numberals in strings - better to avoid the headache and turn it into a number. Cast `pm25` to float before comparing, as so:

```py
    if float(pm25) <= 50 : #edited
        message = "PM 2.5 level is normal"
    else:
        message = "PM 2.5 level is high"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've done this but it still shows the wrong statement. As if the conditions must be the other way around.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have the specs for the database? What kind of data is being returned? I'm also interested to know what the output of `print(pm25, type(pm25))` is - that might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: The database is SQLite3. `pm25` looks like a string: `(' 9.8\n', <type 'str'>)`

Comment: Ah. Gotta cast it to `float` then - updated my answer.